# How do I change google maps points to pop up on hover?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have two points on this map that I have to click on the point to see more information about it. Is there any way to change this so the extra information comes up on mouse hover instead? Here is the map that I am trying to do this on.

http://www.buildinfocus.com/clients/map.php?mapid=29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to listen to a mouseover event to the marker.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    //open the popup
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    //close the popup
});
```

Also have a look at the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html).

Comment: Thanks that worked. Do you know how I could get the info box to close once the mouse rolls off of the info box?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that. The problem with that is that its when you mouseout of the marker and not the info box.

Comment: Ok, I didn´t see that you meant the InfoWindow. I tested to add a normal mouseout event to a div in the InfoWindow but it triggers way to often.. so I don´t know :/.